# В чём отличие LIst<? extends NameClass>, перед List<NameClass>

Tags: java

В чём отличие (1) `List<? extends NameClass>`, перед (2) `List<NameClass>`?

Насколько я понимаю, разница в том, что в (1) мы можем добавлять другие списки с типом `NameClass`, а в (2) это не возможно. Так ли это?

Comment: 1 - все дочерние классы от NameClass, 2 - строго типизированный объект NameClass

Comment: ну так мы же можем кидать наследников в (2) тоже

Comment: Нет, не можем. Не-wildcard дженерики инвариантны.

Comment: @GenCloud если не сложно, напишите чуть более развернутый ответ (с примерами операций, которые не получатся) - думаю, это ровно то, что нужно этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наглядный пример:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();

// Так можно:
List<? extends A> a1 = b;

// А так нельзя (ошибка: Incompatible types):
List<A> a2 = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё пример.

Так можно:

```
class Example<T> {
    Consumer<T> consumer;

    public void consume(List<? extends T> list ) {
        consumer.accept(list.get(0));
    }
}
```

А так нельзя:

```
class Example<T> {
    Consumer<? extends T> consumer;

    public void consume(List<? extends T> list ) {
        consumer.accept(list.get(0));
    }
}
```

Ошибка "Incompatible types: T cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends T" при компиляции вызова `accept()`.

Как обычно, во втором случае можно сделать непроверяемое приведение типа (unchecked cast): `((Consumer<T>)consumer).accept(list.get(0));`, что теоретически позволит пройти примерно половину тестов и насладиться в будущем ловлей насекомых в рантайме.

Comment: @bipll Это пример про `diff((1),(2))`, то есть про "`? extends `"